# Django distinct is not working

Tags: django, postgresql, duplicates, distinct

I have a problem filtering out duplicates from a query.
I'm using Django 1.4 with Postgres 8.4.13

I use this query on my model object (it is a jquery autocomplete)

```
term = request.GET.get('term')
field = request.GET.get('field') 
filter = field + '__' + 'icontains'
model_results = teilnehmer.objects.filter(**{filter: term}).order_by().distinct()
results = [ getattr(x, field) for x in model_results ]
output = simplejson.dumps(results)
```

It works nice, giving me results for any search term in any field of the model.
But it shows every single hit. So if the name "Smith" is in the table 10 times, it gives me an array of 10 times "Smith". 
It should work as a suggestion-tool. I read about distinct and tried to use it (as above) but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Conrad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass field name to `distinct` function:

```
model_results = teilnehmer.objects.filter(**{filter: term}).order_by().distinct(field)
```

Also your approach is very insecure because you should validate `GET` values before passing them to `QuerySet`. Use django forms maybe?

Also read the docs about `distinct` function [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works now.
I'll implement a GET validation now. Django forms is unfortunately no option here, because it is a very complex search form which would have been a lot of work with django forms.
But thanks again!