# Django distinct does not function as intended

Tags: django

I have a Classified table from which I retrieve data as `ct`. 
Each `ct` has a field called Subcategory which is the foreign key for the `Subcategory` table which has a `name` field.

```
ct = Classified.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=q) | Q(subcategory__parent__type__icontains=q) | Q(address__area__icontains=q) | Q(subcategory__name__icontains=q)).filter(active__icontains='yes').filter(address__city__name__exact=cit).order_by('name')
```

I had devised a way to retrieve all unique subcategories from `ct` as follows:

```
cat1 = ct.values_list('subcategory__name', flat=True).distinct()
```

Now this didn't work as I intended and returned multiple copies of the same value in the database. For example, if there were 3 `ct` with the subcategory as `Italian Restaurant`, then `cat1` would return a list where there were 3 appearances of `Italian Restaurant`.

I used a solution from [Django distinct is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398935/django-distinct-is-not-working) and used the following:

```
cat1 = ct.values_list('subcategory__name', flat=True).distinct('name')
```

but this didn't work as well. Any solutions for this problem?

EDIT: Added `ct`

Comment: Which version of django are you using? it works for me. Are you sure you don't have any subtle difference in the names of your subcategories? Specifically, this is the query produced by the orm: u'SELECT DISTINCT `subcategory`.`name` FROM `classified` LEFT OUTER JOIN `subcategory` ON ( `classified `.`subcategory_id` = `subcategory`.`id`)

Comment: In the database, the Subcategory table has just one entry of `Italian Restaurant` but when calling it, it returns two copies.

Comment: Can you check the query the orm produces?

Comment: Checking the query, I noticed that instead of distinct on subcategory, it is `SELECT DISTINCT ON APP_CLASSIFIED.....`. Is this the error area?

Comment: I think you should show us exactly what `ct` is then.

Comment: @Germano, done. Do you need me to add the `Classified` table as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56778/discussion-between-germano-and-newtt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for this is:

```
cat1 = ct.order_by('subcategory__name').values_list('subcategory__name', flat=True).distinct()
```